# Formulário com Struct e Ponteiros

Tags: c, struct

Galera, fiz esse programa para receber nome, endereço e telefone de 2 pessoas, ele recebe os dados da primeira pessoas tranquilamente, os problemas começam com os dados da segunda pessoa, o nome e o endereço da segunda pessoa ele recebe, porém o programa simplesmente pula a entrada do campo telefone e segue pra próxima etapa, que é imprimir as informações na tela, a impressão para os dados do primeiro cadastro acontece normalmente, porém para a segunda pessoas, ele imprime apenas o nome seguido de um número no lugar do endereço que sempre é igual em todos os testes (32767), após isso o programa finaliza, queria entender os por que disso acontecer, já chequei o código várias vezes e não encontrei o erro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Pessoas
{
        char nome[30];
        char endereco[50];
        int telefone;
};

int main ()
{

        int i;
        void print ();
        void recebe ();

        struct Pessoas pessoas[2];

        for (i=0; i!=2; i++)
        {
                recebe(&pessoas[i]);
        }
        printf ("\n\n");
        for (i=0; i!=2; i++)
        {
                print (&pessoas[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}


void recebe (struct Pessoas *y)
{
        fflush (stdin);
        fgets (y->nome, 30, stdin);
        fgets (y->endereco, 50, stdin);
        scanf ("%d", &y->telefone);
}

void print (struct Pessoas *x)
{
        printf ("%s", x->nome);
        printf ("%s", x->endereco);
        printf ("%d", x->telefone);
}
```

Comment: só um detalhe, o comando `for`me parece que ficaria melhor assim: `for (i=0; i<2; i++)`, pq você está iniciando em zero e incrementando de 1 em 1

Answer (score 0):

```
void recebe (struct Pessoas *y)
{
        fflush (stdin);
        fgets (y->nome, 30, stdin);
        fgets (y->endereco, 50, stdin);
        scanf ("%d", &y->telefone);
}
```

Não mistures `fgets()` e `scanf()`

```
void recebe (struct Pessoas *y)
{
        fgets (y->nome, 30, stdin);
        fgets (y->endereco, 50, stdin);
        char tmp[99];
        fgets(tmp, 99, stdin);
        sscanf (tmp, "%d", &y->telefone);
}
```

Lembra-te que o `fgets()` retem o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Talvez queiras retirá-lo para o nome e endereco.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -1):

```
void recebe (struct Pessoas *y)
{
        fflush (stdin);
        fgets (y->nome, 30, stdin);
        fgets (y->endereco, 50, stdin);
        scanf ("%d", &y->telefone);
}
```

Tente receber as entradas de dados da seguinte maneira:

```
scanf(" %30[^\n]s ",&nome);
scanf(" %50[^\n]s ",&endereco);
scanf ("%d", &y->telefone);
```

Comment: 30 ==> 29 e 50 ==> 49 e o 's' está a mais!

Comment: quando utiliza `"  %50[^\n]s"`, o espaço inicial desconsidera qualquer tipo de espaço ou quebra de linha digitado no scanf, `%50` identifico que esse scanf pode pegar ate 50 char `[^\n]` ignora qualquer espaço ou quebra de linha digitado nesse scanf

Comment: pode ser que ele esteja identificando algum espaço ou quebra de linha e isso com que a parte de telefone seja ignorada, por isso eu enviei esse codigo, esta com esse mesmo problema no projeto que estava fazendo, e essa linha de codigo me resolveu.

Comment: A minha ideia era relembrar que `scanf("%3s", p)` pode escrever 3 caracteres **além do `'\0'`**. Se `p` for definido como `char p[4];` não há problema; se for definido como `char p[3];` pode ocorrer *buffer overflow*.

Comment: Oh! O "s" que está a mais é este: `%[^ ]s`.

Comment: A sintaxe para receber uma string por meio da scanf() é:`scanf(“%s”, nome_da_string);`